# How can I get LaTeX chemnum package to work alongside .png images?

Tags: overleaf, thesis, eps, chemistry, chemnum

I have been trying (for too long now) to get LaTeX to automatically label chemical compounds in my document in overleaf in combination with being able to add .png images using the \insertgraphics commmand.

I have tried starting from templates which already have the automatic numbering in place where chemdraws are prepopulated with TMP1, TMP2, etc. in .eps files (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/automatically-numbering-compounds-in-chemical-schemes/kybckmsxnshs).

Unfortunately I then can't added figures using .png files as I start getting error messages about 'Cannot determine size of graphic in file.png (no BoundingBox). Undefined control sequence.'

Does anyone know of a way that I can start adding pictures to this code below please? Literally being able to add any image will do.

The hexa.eps file is available if you follow the link.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Automatically numbering compounds in chemical schemes}


%% Uncomment these lines if you get error about "too many \new..." 
% \let\tmp\newinsert
% \let\newinsert\newbox
\usepackage{chemstyle}
% \let\newinsert\tmp
\usepackage{chemnum}

% For positioning the scheme captions at the top.
\floatsetup[scheme]{position=top}

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}
%% hexa.eps has "TMP1" and "TMP2" as the markers
%% in fact EVERY .eps should start with TMP1, TMP2 etc
%% for ease of use
\replacecmpd{first:compound}  %% automatically replace TMP1
\replacecmpd{second:compound}  %% automatically replace TMP2
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{hexa}
\caption{This is something!}
\label{first:chem:scheme}
\end{scheme}

Compounds \refcmpd{first:compound} and \refcmpd{second:compound} in \ref{first:chem:scheme}. Here's a reference to in-text creation of \cmpd{RareCompound} that we can later refer to.

\vfill

\begin{scheme}
\replacecmpd{next:compound} %% automatically replace TMP1 BUT the autonumbering counter updates to 3!
\replacecmpd{last:compound} %% automatically replace TMP2
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{hexa}
\caption{This is something else!}
\label{second:chem:scheme}
\end{scheme}

Compounds \refcmpd{next:compound} and \refcmpd{last:compound} in \ref{second:chem:scheme}. Hey remember \cmpd{RareCompound}? \texttt{chemnum} still remembers it correctly, \emph{and} see how the compound numbering continues throughout the scheme diagrams!

\vfill

%% MANUAL UPDATING THE COMPOUND COUNTER; make sure you know what you're doing!
\setcounter{cmpdmain}{8} 

\begin{scheme}
\replacecmpd{jumped:compound} %% automatically replace TMP1 BUT the autonumbering counter updates to 9!
\replacecmpd{nextjumped:compound} %% automatically replace TMP2
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{hexa}
\caption{This is again something else!}
\label{third:chem:scheme}
\end{scheme}

Compounds \refcmpd{jumped:compound} and \refcmpd{nextjumped:compound} in \ref{third:chem:scheme}. (Yes we manually modified the compound numbering counter after \ref{second:chem:scheme}).



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Thanks for your code. Are the two \end statements I added (once approved) correct? Can you add a screenshot which shows your result and indicate what you are missing?

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking a look, yes those are correct. I've included a screenshot of the reaction scheme I want to label.

Comment: Did you follow the chemnum-tag? 77 questions.

Comment: I have tried digging through the questions that have been asked already an using fragments from their code to see if it will fix the issue with no luck e.g. \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf} in the preamble

Comment: Just had a closer look. A few things: 1) Too many packages are included, which are not needed to reproduce the problem. I.e. they hinder or complicate compile elsewhere. 2) It refers to images, which are at least out of my reach. // Suggestions: It would be good to prune this code to its essential: missing numbers under the figures. It would be good, to have access to your 3 images.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments, you're right, the question and code is too complicated, I've tried to simplify it down a bit, does the above have everything you need?

Comment: Seems to be better at quick glance. However, I’m not sure, whether or not the .eps files are needed to produce correct labels,

Comment: From what I've read, you need the chemical structures in .eps format with temporary labels so that the text can still be read and replaced.

Comment: Having done this for my MSc and PhD dissertations a few years back, I am quite sure that you need the structures in .eps format.